# Calling member function of one class from another

Tags: c++, oop, function-pointers

I have this problem with a big piece of code which have some event handling objects. In an event handling class I am trying to call a function of another class through pointer but it is having same error as this code have which I have implemented to just check the logic that I am using to call there. What is wrong I am doing here?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class FunctionPointer;
class UseFP
{
public:
    UseFP(void){}
    ~UseFP(void){}

    void Modified(int m,int n);
    void (FunctionPointer::*update)(int,int);

};

void UseFP::Modified(int m,int n)
    {
            //(this->*update)(m,n);// call by fp if I uncomment it it gives error.
    }

class FunctionPointer
{
    int a,b;
    UseFP * obj;
public:
    FunctionPointer(void);

    ~FunctionPointer(void);

    void updateData(int m, int n)
    {
        a = m;
        b = n;
        cout<<"\n\nUpdated: a "<<a<<", b "<<b<<endl;
    }

    void Input()
    {
        int m, n;
        cout<<"\nEnter new data: ";
        cin>>m>>n;
        obj->Modified(m,n);
    }
    };

void main()
{
    FunctionPointer obj;
    obj.Input();
}
```

errors after uncommenting function call

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FunctionPointer, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>main.cpp
1>c:\users\volmo\desktop\functionpointer\functionpointer\functionpointer.h(14) : error C2440: 'newline' : cannot convert from 'UseFP *const ' to 'FunctionPointer *const '
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\users\volmo\desktop\functionpointer\functionpointer\functionpointer.h(14) : error C2647: '->*' : cannot dereference a 'void (__thiscall FunctionPointer::* )(int,int)' on a 'UseFP *const '
1>Generating Code...
1>Compiling...
1>FunctionPointer.cpp
1>c:\users\volmo\desktop\functionpointer\functionpointer\functionpointer.h(14) : error C2440: 'newline' : cannot convert from 'UseFP *const ' to 'FunctionPointer *const '
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>c:\users\volmo\desktop\functionpointer\functionpointer\functionpointer.h(14) : error C2647: '->*' : cannot dereference a 'void (__thiscall FunctionPointer::* )(int,int)' on a 'UseFP *const '
1>Generating Code...
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\volmo\Desktop\FunctionPointer\FunctionPointer\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>FunctionPointer - 4 error(s), 0 warning(s)
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: For C++ member functions, there is a hidden "zeroth" argument that is the `this` pointer. This makes using member function pointers non-trivial. You might want to read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) which will help you with all of that.

Comment: Also, please post the complete error message *from the program in the question*. The error message references something called `newline`, but there is no such thing in the code sample in the question.

Comment: Please check Question again I have edited error messages.

Comment: Beware that `main` **must not** have return type `void`. Modern compilers will not compile your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update` is typed as a "pointer to member function of class `FunctionPointer`. This means it requires a `FunctionPointer` instance on the left of `->*`. But you're trying to dereference it with `this` which is of type `UseFP`. Hence the error.

You need an instance of `FunctionPointer` to invoke `update` on it. I don't know what your intended semantics is, but one way to obtain one would be to add a parameter to `Modified`:

```
void UseFP::Modified(FunctionPointer &fp, int m,int n)
    {
            (fp.*update)(m,n);
    }
```

Comment: I am using this concept without using function pointer as: void Modify(FunctionPointer * fp){fp->updateData(m,n);} I thought passing a complete object pointer and making updateData as public for sake of this is not good. so i tried function pointers.

Comment: But you're not using a *function pointer,* you're using a *member function pointer.* These are **very** different things. A member function pointer (more precisely, "pointer to member function") is not really a pointer; it's more like an "offset," identifying a member function *within a class.* You still need an instance on which to invoke it.

Comment: yeah of course the way you told is working :) and with keeping updateData in private too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do such things. You should pass `FunctionPointer` object to function `Modified`, or store as class variable.

```
void UseFP::Modified(FunctionPointer* p, int m,int n)
    {
       (p->*update)(m,n);// call by fp if I uncomment it it gives error.
    }
```

And call it like

```
obj->Modified(this,m,n);
```